# Error: installing ruby-debug-ide

Tags: ruby-debug

The truth is that i am new to ruby on rails development.
Not that i can not install the gem install ruby-debug-ide on aptana studio 3.

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide  
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...


Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debu
g-ide-0.4.16 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/ext/
gem_make.out
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: tl;dr: what made the difference is this command: `gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre`

Answer (score 9):

Since it seems you have DevKit installed already, run this command

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --platform=ruby --pre
```

As mentioned in that post, it's a bug fixed in not yet released version of ruby-debug-ide

Edit:

This seems to work (Windows 7 64 bit):

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide --pre

gem install ruby-debug-base19x --pre
```

Comment: I have installed gem using Terminal. If i run rb file using Debug run , still my code doesn't stop on the break point. But i have below message in the console:    Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:54292